# xmlWorker not found in iTexsharp.dll asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I added the refrence of iTextsharp.dll in my asp.net c# project and also added

```
using iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser;
```

but could not found XmlWorker.How  can I  use xmlWorker in my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Compiler errors with iTextSharp xmlworkerhelper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956740/asp-net-compiler-errors-with-itextsharp-xmlworkerhelper)

Comment: @ChrisHaas it's not a Duplicate it has nothing to do with ASP.net

Answer (score 0):

Its not available with that package , try to download it separately.  I have used the following link 
http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_itextsharp/downloads/xmlworker/xmlworker-5.5.4/itextsharp.xmlworker-all-5.5.4.zip/